# JSONObject can't read attribute from existing object even though object is correctly instanced

Tags: javascript, java, json, http, web

I have problem with reading json attribute even though object correctly instanced.

First, I send json from client side with JavaScript:

```
let object = {
        firstName: document.getElementById("firstName").value,
        lastName: document.getElementById("lastName").value,
        username: document.getElementById("username").value,
        password: document.getElementById("password").value,
        email: document.getElementById("email").value,
        action: "registration"
}

let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
...
```

On server side I have code:

```
req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    // String address = "/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp";
    StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            jb.append(line);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        /* report an error */ }

    try {
        jsonObject = HTTP.toJSONObject(jb.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // crash and burn
        throw new IOException("Error parsing JSON request string");
    }

    String action = jsonObject.getString("firstName");
```

jsonObject exists but program throws org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["firstName"] not found.

Object on server side when I use debugger:
[image]

Comment: Looking into the image (debugger) `Request-URI` and `Method` are your keys firstName is a value for the key `Method`.

If you want to get the json structure copy that json string and parse using any json formatter online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no key with a name like `firstName` in your `jsonObject`. Instead, you need to search for `Method` property and then parse the `firstName` from it. First, declare a `GetQueryMap` method:

```
public static Map<String, String> GetQueryMap(String query)  
{  
    String[] params = query.split("&");  
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
    for (String param : params)  
    {  
        String [] p=param.split("=");
        String name = p[0];  
        if(p.length>1)  {
           String value = p[1];  
           map.put(name, value);
        }  
    }  
    return map;  
}
```

Then use it like:

```
String method = jsonObject.getString("Method");
Map params = GetQueryMap(method);
String firstName = (String)params.get("firstName");
String lastName = (String)params.get("lastName");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're not sending the data correctly from the browser side.
are you sending the correct `content-type` header (`application/json`)?
Are you serializing the object correctly for sending?